# Eclipse won't run current class

Tags: java, eclipse

I have several java files in the same package and only one of them runs. When I try to run files from previous projects those work, but the one I'm currently working on does not. I've attempted to adjust run configurations as I've seen suggested on here but the file I want to run doesn't even show up as an option.
I'm trying to run balloon and only islands is compiling

[Picture of run configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dmkb7.png)

Additionally, when I right click in the project sidebar, there's no option to run as Java application as there is on the other files.

UPDATE: I emptied and recreated my work space and this was the result. Now it doesn't run any new java files
[Problem 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UD1HO.png)

UPDATE 2: I have now tried uninstalling and reinstalling eclipse and it still does not work. Starting to get a little desperate

Comment: UPDATE: I have cleared and recreated my work space and now it doesn't run any new java files

Answer (score 3):

I know it's no longer an issue for the original poster but new programmers may run into this.

You likely forgot to add `String[] args` in your main method. This means the program will default to running another class, likely whatever was ran last.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

}
```

This was a really basic issue that anyone with decent experience would likely not think of hence what I assume to be the reason for the lack of replies.

P.S. I just jumped back into coding and ran into this a couple minutes ago.

Answer (score 2):

You can try right clicking on java file(Balloon) and select Run As java application(it will show this option if you have main method in class).

It did not work then clear the workspace and try to import the project once again. there is chance you have corrupted the workspace.

Comment: What is the safest way to clear and reimport without risking lost work?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that they are in the src package before they work.

Answer (score 1):

you can clear the project and clear all the error log , then they will run suc

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of the (.java) file to the class name that contains the main method. This applies if you have multiple classes in the same program. If you have a single class then the issue will be with the main method. Make sure you have typed the main method correctly.

Comment: If you could provide an example of what you mean in what you want them to do that would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Check that your main class name is the same as your file name, if not, try adding the package name to the top of the program.